# How to change data type in Excel file before creating feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, features, import, excel

I am trying to import data from Excel spreadsheets where each point coordinate has a 'datetime' timestamp (e.g. "2012-06-01 14:45:32") associated to it. When I check the table properties ArcGIS 10 always recognizes the timestamp field as 'date' (i.e. "2012-06-01") and drops the time-of-the-day info.

Is there a way to import the timestamp field as a full datetime type? And if yes, how do I go about it?

Comment: What type of storage are you importing into?  Personal GDB, File GDB, Shapefile, etc?

Comment: That would be a Shapefile. I am using the "Create Feature Class.. > From XY Table" function in ArcCatalog

Comment: Found a rather disheartening forum discussion about this topic -> [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=986&t=252973)

Comment: Tomm, shapefiles store data in dBase III/IV format. This reply describes some of the limitations: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25762/664.  Clearly no date+time field can be stored as a dBase date field. Workarounds could include (i) importing into a GDB, (ii) importing the timestamps as numeric values, and (iii) creating an Excel macro to split the timestamp into a date field and a separate numeric (or string) field for the time only.  (The macro--which you can create by recording your actions in one workbook--can then quickly be applied to all the workbooks.)

Comment: To follow up on @whuber's comment, why are you importing to a shapefile instead of a File GDB or a Personal GDB?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, importing to a Personal GDB works as long as the time field is imported as text. Not quite what I had hoped for but at least I can add meaningful labels to my data points now. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 4):

If it's a .csv file you can edit the [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file so that it includes a [custom date format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
DateTimeFormat=YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:s
```

Comment: Well, I've got 15 excel files with around 3-4 worksheets each. It would be quite a nuisance if I'd had to export each worksheet to CSV first. There must be a way to tell Arcatalog to use the correct data type...