# AGOL "Update Data" from Excel import numeric columns with some NULL rows?

Tags: arcgis-online, import, excel, null

I need to append some new features into an ArcGIS Online hosted feature layer.  The data has been supplied to me in an Excel file (including X/Y columns).  I was intending to import it as-is using the hosted feature layer's "Update Data" button.

However, when I get to the field-matching phase of the process, there are some numeric fields in the hosted layer for which it will not let me select the corresponding column from the spreadsheet.  It appears as though this is because that column is blank for some records.

If I change the blank values to '0' (zero), then it will let me select those columns.  So I guess if not every value in the column is a number, then it assumes it must be a text field (and I can select it to import into text fields).

However, these columns need to be imported into number fields, and these blank values MUST NOT be imported as zeros, as that would simple be incorrect and result in wrong analysis.  They need to be imported as NULLs.  I've tried changing the values to `null`, `<NULL>` or `#N/A` but none of these worked - only `0` worked.

The hosted layer field is configured to allow null values.

Is there any way to import directly from an Excel spreadsheet into an AGOL hosted feature layer where NULLs can be imported for a numeric attribute?

(Otherwise, my work around may have to be to convert it to a Shapefile or fGDB first, massage the data there, and import that.  I'm really hoping to avoid this!)

Comment: Check if the field has "Allows Null Values" = Yes. Open the layer page in AGOL, click Data, Fields, select your Field to see its settings. I don't know how to or if its possible to change it if it is set to No.

Comment: It is set to Yes for allows null values.  I'll update the question to include this.

Comment: Adding 8 extra rows at the START of the spreadsheet and setting "0" (zero) for all numeric fields seems to work around the issue.  Requires deleting all 8 of them manually in AGOL map view afterwards of course.  This is not a solution though... just a dodgy work around.

Comment: Try sorting the Excel file so all the null values are in the last rows?  Assuming you have at least eight non-null records.

Comment: There are actually several numeric fields which may have nulls in them, for different records.  So there is no guarantee that such a sort is not going to result in nulls near the top for other fields.

Comment: Last guess, then I got nothing... Try formatting those columns as number instead of general in Excel?

Comment: All good suggestions.  But it have already checked/ tried that one too.

Comment: Duplicate question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27390/importing-data-with-empty-cells-without-gis-replacing-the-empty-cell-with-0

Replace blank/null cells with -999 (integers) or -999e-99 (doubles).

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate.   That other question was for ArcGIS Desktop.  This one is for ArcGIS Online.  The other question results in blanks being imported as zeros.  This question results in the import not being possible at all.