# Why is ArcGis change precision of double field after copy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes, precision

I create the attribute table of a shapefile and while I copy it by using the "copy features" tool it change the precision from 11 to 14. I create two fields with the name poly_x and poly_y and they represent the centroid of the polygon.

I use ArcGis 10.2.1 and the attribute contain some text fields and two float fields which contain the X and Y coords of the cendroid of the polygon, with precision 11 and scale 3. After I use the above mentioned tool the precision is change to 14 and the scale remain the same.

I would like to mention also, when I insert the shapefiles in QGIS even if I define the precision 11 and scale 3 I see that the precision is 12 and the scale remain the same. The same thing happens when I add the data in Arcgis 9.3.1.

Comment: You'll need to **edit** the question to provide the dBase table definition before and after copy, and the version of ArcGIS involved

Comment: Related (maybe even duplicate): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28695/

Comment: I have update the question, and I would like to ask if I want to have precision 11 should I define the precision 10, and if is that true why is this happen?